# How to detect that multiple UIGestureRecognizers end?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, multi-touch

in my view I have multiple gesture recognizers (UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer) and I allowed them to detect touches simultaneously:

```swift
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                       shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view {
       return false
    }

    return true
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I am no longer able to detect when all the 3 gestures end. I cannot use

```swift
    if gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .cancelled {
    }
```

bacause this is valid only for a gesture recognizer and not for the all 3.

Any idea if there an api to detect when all active recognizers end?

Thanks

---

**Solution**

This works but it is very ugly: basically I keep track when all three gestures recognizers end and prevent to detect the end multiple times as the recognizers callback can be called in any order:

```swift
class SCCanvasViewController: UIViewController {
    var gesturesAlreadyEnded = false

    lazy var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let gr = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        gr.delegate = self
        return gr
    }()

    lazy var pinchGestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer = {
        let gr = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
        gr.delegate = self
        return gr
    }()

    lazy var rotateGestureRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer = {
        let gr = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotation(_:)))
        gr.delegate = self
        return gr
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func isGestureEnded(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .cancelled || gesture.state == .failed
    }

    func allGesturesEnded() -> Bool {
        let panEnded = isGestureEnded(gesture: panGestureRecognizer)
        let pinchEnded = isGestureEnded(gesture: pinchGestureRecognizer)
        let rotationEnded = isGestureEnded(gesture: rotateGestureRecognizer)
        return panEnded && pinchEnded && rotationEnded
    }

    @objc func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            gesturesAlreadyEnded = false
        }

        if !gesturesAlreadyEnded && isGestureEnded(gesture: gesture) {
            canvasView.showHorizontalSnapIndicators(areVisible: false)
            canvasView.showVerticalSnapIndicators(areVisible: false)
            if (allGesturesEnded()) {
                gesturesAlreadyEnded = true
                print("Can create transformation command")
            }
            return
        }
    }

    @objc func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            gesturesAlreadyEnded = false
        }

        if !gesturesAlreadyEnded && isGestureEnded(gesture: gesture) {
            if (allGesturesEnded()) {
                gesturesAlreadyEnded = true
                print("Can create transformation command")
            }
            return
        }
    }

    @objc func handleRotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            gesturesAlreadyEnded = false
        }

        if !gesturesAlreadyEnded && isGestureEnded(gesture: gesture) {
            if (allGesturesEnded()) {
                gesturesAlreadyEnded = true
                print("Can create transformation command")
            }
            return
        }
    }
}

extension SCCanvasViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view {
           return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Examine the touches? I mean, what does “all gestures ended” even mean? It means no fingers are touching the screen, yes?

Comment: I need to detect when all fingers of the all three gesture recognizers are lifted. For example, if I am panning and pinching and the same time, when I lift the first finger, the pinch is gesture is ended but the user can still pan the view. When the user lifts the second finger then also pan ends and I need to detect this event to update my UI.

Comment: Well, as I said, you are getting touch events. You _know_ when all three fingers leave the screen. That is exactly when "all gestures are lifted". What else is there to know?

Comment: So have you adopted the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol? So are you set up to receive touch events or not? You said you can't poll for the information, but you don't need to if events are delivered. And you should be able to enable multitouch and then get notified with a set of gestures ending individually or simultaneously

Comment: Yes, basically I just added actions to listen for gesture events not single UITouches and kept track of when all the gestures ended.

Answer (score 1):

Set it up to get multi-touch notifications, then examine the set of touches impacted by the event.

```
class TouchableView: UIView {
   var touchViews = [UITouch:TouchSpotView]() 

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
   }

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      for touch in touches {
         createViewForTouch(touch: touch)
      }
   }

   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      for touch in touches {
         let view = viewForTouch(touch: touch) 
         // Move the view to the new location.
         let newLocation = touch.location(in: self)
         view?.center = newLocation
      }
   }

   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      for touch in touches {
         removeViewForTouch(touch: touch)
      }
   }

   override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      for touch in touches {
         removeViewForTouch(touch: touch)
      }
   }

   // Other methods. . . 
}
```

Comment: I cannot see how this can work. I have 3 gestures recognizer attached to the view (Pan, Pinch and Rotation) that are executed simultaneously. I do not keep track of single touches to recognise the gestures.

Comment: @libe define 'simultaneously'? You can't pan and pinch at the same time or pan and rotate at the same time...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620005-touchesended?language=objc

Comment: yes you can run multiple gesture recognizers simultaneously, please see here: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures

Comment: The part I was asking for disambiguation about, I'm asking about whether you meant that touches happened simultaneously or you were referring to simply having multiple recognizers active simultaneously.